# Wireless network disabled on a Broadcom 4312

Tags: 11.04, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

After installing Ubuntu 11.04, my network has become disabled.
Here is the output of`lshw` in terminal:

```
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: 00:21:00:58:65:5f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.38 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE
802.11bg
       resources: irq:17 memory:d4600000-d4603fff
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have the switch off, or you might have turned the WiFi off in Windows using the Function keys.

If this is not the case, have you installed the restricted drivers for your card? To do this, search for 'additional drivers' in your Dash and/or Preferences. Make sure you have it hooked up to the internet by a lan cable to download any firmware, etc.

If that doesn't help, then disable the restricted drivers in `Additional Drivers` and install [`firmware-b43-installer`](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Ubuntu.2FDebian).

Answer (score 0):

Try shutting down(if not already off), disconnecting the power, remove battery(if it is a laptop), press power a few times to release stored energy, reinsert battery(if it is a laptop), reconnect AC power. Turn on computer. Worked for me. After trying multiple fixes I found on the internet I remembered reading this somewhere. My hardware was blocked via a hardware switch(fn+f8) which doesn't work in ubuntu(works with windows, but uninstalled windows). rfkill showed 0: phy0: Wireless Lan as Hard Blocked.